# Use Wildcard SSL with Amazon EC2 instance, secure.mydomain.com -> EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I recently purchased my first wildcard SSL certificate and I am trying to use it to secure the connection between my site (Cent OS 6 VPS) and an Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04.

My primary site currently has a wildcard subdomain configured, *.mysite.com, with which the wildcard SSL is working. I am trying to use the SSL with secure.mysite.com, a CNAME record pointing to my EC2 instance public DNS.

I was able to locate several tutorials on installing SSL certificates on EC2 instances and Route 53 looks promising, but I am not sure which path to start down. I am fairly new to dealing with SSL certificates and this type of DNS configuration.

The EC2 instance's security group includes HTTPS (443) but a ping of port 443 on the instance reveals that it is closed. When I attempt to navigate to https://secure.mydomain.com, I immediately receive a "Web Page Not Available" error - http://secure.mydomain.com works fine (loads the EC2 instance).

Any guidance on this matter would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Why the down vote? If more information would help I would be pleased to offer it, just let me know what you need. I am trying to avoid spending hours following the wrong path trying to make this work, just looking for some guidance.

Comment: Are you using apache on the ec2 Instance? If so, could you post the part of the apache configuration you have for your domain?

Comment: Yes, the instance is running apache - could you elaborate on which part you are asking for? There is nothing domain specific on the instance itself, I have been accessing it using either the IP or public DNS address given by Amazon

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by installing my SSL onto an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer instance and pointing it to my EC2 instance. Thanks to the folks on Stack Overflow for quickly offering solid advice on the matter.